# Configuring Windows search service programmatically, is it possible?

Tags: windows, desktop-search

I work on a piece of software that manages reads/writes to an area of the user's profile using a filter driver.  I've realised that Windows search service get's confused by our filter driver and this area of disk needs to be excluded from search (which doesn't make sense for this area anyway).

I've realised that it's possible, programatically, to add an exclusion to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\DefaultRules
```

And restart the service to pick it up.  However, this is a bit heavy.  Does anyone know if it's possible to do this kind of thing in a more elegant way?  I looked at the Search SDK but that seemed to be more aimed at people wanting to use the search data rather than configuring the service.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was possible without direct registry manipulation using:

[The Crawl Scope Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb266541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Now part of SDK 7+)